Calculating quantity of sight using Viewshed in QGIS
I am looking for a solution to map the visibility of an high object as i.e. a mast, but not only by looking from where the mast is visible, but also how much of the mast is visible in meters, with the aim of being able to make statements, from where you can see significantly more of the mast and where perhaps only a few cm.

First, create a set of points at the mast location with observ_hgt, target_hgt and radius values, like this:

Then running a viewshed is going to consider an observer at those heights up a mast, and whether they can see a target 1.6m above the DEM, ie can they make eye contact with someone on the ground. So can the person on the ground see that point on the mast. Don't use the "GDAL Viewshed" function which looks a bit trickier to automate. Instead, I'm using the "Visibility Analysis" plugin from the standard plugin store https://landscapearchaeology.org/qgis-visibility-analysis/.

The viewshed tool needs those attributes to have those names. Run it:

I'm not sure how much effect refraction and curvature has in your application, you could try both and see if it makes much difference. The important things are the analysis type, location and dem layers, and combining multiple outputs parameters. You get back a raster layer of how many points on the mast can be seen from the ground.
I've put my mast on a spur overlooking ground to the north, you can see how there's no visibility to the south of the mast because of the rising ground, points on the plane to the far NW can see it all, but there's a zone of invisibility just over the steep ground near NW of the mast. You can also see partial visibility, where only the top can be seen, in the valley W of the mast.

This assumes that if you can only see N points on the mast then its the top N points, but I think that's always true if you have a 2.5D DEM. If you have full 3D and an overhang you might see the bottom of a mast and not the top!
Note that everything - the DEM CRS and heights, the location coordinates etc, should all be in metres for simplicity.
